# Distance traveled by a projectile

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Like the title says, I want to find the **distance** traveled by a particle in projectile motion (2-D).

I tried rectifying the curve above the $x$-axis and finding the length of the curve as
$$\int \sqrt{(y')^2 + 1}\space dx$$
where the projectile travels from $x = 0$ to $x = \frac{u^2 \sin2\theta}{g}$ and I use the standard equation of a parabola to express $y$ in terms of $x$, i.e. $$y = x \tan\theta - \frac{x^2 g}{2u^2 \cos^2 \theta}$$
I am just not able to evaluate the integral for the formula. Can anyone give me some pointers on integrating the function?
And, is the function actually integrable?

Comment: You will be integrating $\sqrt{Q(x)}$ where $Q(x)$ is a quadratic polynomial which is always positive. Completing the square, we get $Q(x)=p^2(x-a)^2+q^2$. Make the substitution $p(x-a)=q\sinh t$ (better) or $p(x-a)=\tan t$.

Comment: The idea is not really complicated. Differentiate $y$. We get something of shape $a-bx$. Square, add $1$. We get $b^2x^2-2abx+a^2+1$. Make the substitution $bx-a=\sinh t$. Look up the integral of $\cosh^2 t$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I get $\int \sqrt{(y')^2 + 1} \space dx = bx - a$ after evaluating it (With substitution $bx - a = \sinh (t)$. How is that possible?

Comment: Not possible. You end up integrating $\frac{1}{b}\cosh^2 t$. Maybe you forgot that we get a $\cosh t$ term from the square root, and another one from $bx=\cosh t$ and therefore $b\,dx=\cosh t\,dt$.

Comment: Yes, I get  $1\over b$ $[t + \sinh t\cosh t]$. Is there any other substitution without hyperbolic functions?

Comment: Yes, we can let $bx-a=\tan t$. We end up integrating a constant times $\sec^3 t$.